# Storm topology reading from rabbitmq message queue at runtime

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-storm

Can a Storm topology read from RabbitMQ queue at runtime? The topology is submitted in a cluster using `StormSubmitter` class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. You can pretty much do anything. If you are asking whether is a pre-made spout for RabbitMQ, I don't know an established one but there are a few according to google.